# VBScript to return Windows Product Key

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBScript to return the Windows Product Key. I found some VBScripts online but these are specific to certain Windows versions. Is there a VBScript available that would work on Windows 7 - Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 6):

You can try [this code](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=42793):

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
strValueName = "DigitalProductId"
strComputer = "."
dim iValues()

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
  strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
oReg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,iValues

Dim arrDPID
arrDPID = Array()
For i = 52 to 66
  ReDim Preserve arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) + 1 )
  arrDPID( UBound(arrDPID) ) = iValues(i)
Next
' <--- Create an array to hold the valid characters for a microsoft Product Key --->
Dim arrChars
arrChars = Array("B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9")

' <--- The clever bit !!! (Decrypt the base24 encoded binary data) --->
For i = 24 To 0 Step -1
  k = 0
  For j = 14 To 0 Step -1
    k = k * 256 Xor arrDPID(j)
    arrDPID(j) = Int(k / 24)
    k = k Mod 24
  Next
  strProductKey = arrChars(k) & strProductKey
  ' <--- add the "-" between the groups of 5 Char --->
  If i Mod 5 = 0 And i <> 0 Then strProductKey = "-" & strProductKey
Next
strFinalKey = strProductKey

' <--- This part of the script displays operating system Information and the license Key --->
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
  strOS   = objOperatingSystem.Caption
  strBuild   = objOperatingSystem.BuildNumber
  strSerial   = objOperatingSystem.SerialNumber
  strRegistered  = objOperatingSystem.RegisteredUser
Next

Set wshShell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strPopupMsg = strOS & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Build Number:  " & strBuild & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "PID:  " & strSerial & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Registered to:  " & strRegistered & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strPopupMsg = strPopupMsg & "Your Windows Product Key is:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strFinalKey
strPopupTitle = "Microsoft Windows License Information"
wshShell.Popup strPopupMsg,,strPopupTitle,vbCancelOnly+vbinformation
```

Comment: @Hackoo Please don't post other people's code without proper attribution.

Comment: Do you think that I can get this to echo the computer name and Windows Product Key to a file `\\server\share\list.txt` so I can set it as a logon script and it will generate a list in `list.txt`?